# Get Youtube access token after page reload with Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, youtube-api, firebase-authentication

I want users to have access to their Youtube playlists after signing in with Google through Firebase. I use `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)` for signing in and I can get their access token with `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` and everything works perfectly just after they signed in.

The problem is that I can't get their access token back if they refresh the page. Firebase automatically signs them in again but `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` returns

```js
{user: null, credential: undefined, operationType: undefined}
```

I have tried the method used in Google's [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) but I don't know where to get the authorization code used in step 2.

I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't provide a way to refresh a Google access token. Perhaps you are better off using Google web sign in SDK to obtain the Google access token: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
It also refreshes that for you automatically.
You can then pass the Google access token or ID token to sign in with Firebase:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken));
```